# Magento Migrate customers with no password.

Tags: magento

I am migrating an outdated Saas site to a new magento enterprise install and don't believe I'm going to be able to transfer the customers passwords. They are encrypted using the Perl crypt() function.

I'm wondering what the best workflow for this might be, as I'm sure others must have run into something similar.

I don't mind having to send out an email asking all our customers to create a new password, or asking them to the next time they log in.

But what should I put in the password field for import? For security I surely can't give everyone the same temporary password.

We have almost 123,000 customers (many of whom are probably no longer active though) so it may take a little while.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way is to auto-generate passwords along with the accounts, all using Magento's built-in functionality, as demonstrated below:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');

$password = '123456';
$email = 'testuser@test.com';

$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
$customer->loadByEmail($email);

if(!$customer->getId()) { // if customer does not already exists, by email
    // new data
    $customer->setEmail($email);
    $customer->setFirstname('Johnny');
    $customer->setLastname('Doels');
    $newPassword = $customer->generatePassword(); // generate a new password
    $customer->changePassword($newPassword); // set it

} else {
    // do something here for existing customers
}

try {
    $customer->save();
    $customer->setConfirmation(null);
    $customer->save();
    $customer->sendPasswordReminderEmail(); // save successful, send new password
}

catch (Exception $ex) {
    //Zend_Debug::dump($ex->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: I have used  $customer->setPassword($newPassword); instead of $customer->changePassword($newPassword);

Comment: What Magento version are you using? The above was tested with 1.6 and above.

Comment: I am using Magento CE 1.7 version

Answer (score 2):

> As indicated by this wiki page, Magento supports salted as well as
>   unsalted MD5 hashes. This is technically true, but getting it to work
>   it’s all that straightforward.
>
> Basically, you need to copy over MD5 hashed passwords with an empty
>   string as the salt.
>
> E.g., take the password “foobar”, the MD5 hash is
>   “3858f62230ac3c915f300c664312c63f”. If you put this directly in the
>   db, it won’t work. The authentication system looks for a “:” in the
>   password hash to get the salt. Bottom line, add a “:” to the end and
>   Magento will salt the password with nothing, so you just get the
>   regular MD5 hash back.
>
> “3858f62230ac3c915f300c664312c63f” ->
>   “3858f62230ac3c915f300c664312c63f:”

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/16700/
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/customer

You can also simply randomly create the passwords, they are one way hashed and customers can easily reset their password to generate a new password that would be emailed to them instead of trying to import existing passwords.

Comment: Thanks, yeah they are not MD5 hashed passwords. I will have to create random passwords and have them reset them. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Resetting users passwords would be my very last resort. If you know what hashing method was used to encrypt the passwords then you should not need to reset passwords.

Migrate the customers passwords into the magento database as their hash and salt combo. You can then overload the password hashing method in magento to check if the customer has an old has an old hash or a new hash.

If the customer has an old hash use your old crypt method and salt to check the password. If you wanted to you could then update to the new method it successfully authenticated.

If you are able to create the hash function in php that would be easiest. Alternatively just call a perl program from php.